# Obtaining solution using matrix operations without using any solver

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have the following problem:

$$Min \sum_i \sum_j(1-m_j)x_{ij}+\sum_i \sum_jn_jy_{ij}+\sum_iz_{i}$$
$$s.t:x_{ij} \leq b_{ij}$$
$$x_{ij}+y_{ij}+z_i \geq d_{ij}$$

Given information:

$m_j$ and $n_j$ are binary parameters and their values are known.

$0 \leq m_j \leq n_j \leq 1$

$x_{ij},y_{ij},z_i \geq 0$

$0\leq b_{ij}\leq d_{ij} \leq 1$

I know that to solve this problem we do not need to use any solver. But I am not sure how. How can this problem be solved without using any optimization solver, by using only matrix operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @whpowell96 observed, the problem decomposes by $i$ into independent subproblems.  Each subproblem $i$ can indeed be solved by inspection as follows.  Because $x_{ij}$, $y_{ij}$, and $z_i$ all appear in the “demand” constraint with the same coefficient $1$, an optimal solution can be obtained by initializing all variables to $0$ and then increasing them according to increasing order of their objective coefficients $1-m_j$, $n_j$, and $1$. Because of the upper bound on $x_{ij}$, it should be increased only up to $b_{ij}$. First exhaust all variables with a $0$ objective coefficient ($1-m_j=0$ or $n_j=0$), and then increase $z_i$ until each LHS $\ge d_{ij}$.

---

A simpler alternative optimal solution that does not require sorting is as follows:
\begin{align}
x^*_{ij} &= \begin{cases} b_{ij} &\text{if $m_j=1$} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\
y^*_{ij} &= \begin{cases} d_{ij} &\text{if $n_j=0$ (hence $m_j=0$)} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\
z^*_i &= \max_j (d_{ij}-x^*_{ij}-y^*_{ij})
\end{align}
The resulting optimal objective value is $\sum_i z^*_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $1\leq i\leq M$ and $1\leq j\leq N$. This is not a complete solution, but I have reduced this problem into $M$ independent linear programs which can then be solved by the simplex method.

We begin by noticing that your objective is a sum of $M$ terms each independent of each other. Furthermore, each constraint indexed by $i$ is also independent. Therefore, we can separate the problem into $M$ independent subproblems and minimize each independently. We proceed by dropping the $i$ subscript and describing a single subproblem. The objective of the subproblem is given by
$$
\min \sum_{j=1}^N(1-m_j)x_j + \sum_{j=1}^N n_jy_j + z.
$$

The linear program for this subproblem is given by

$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{X\in\mathbb{R}^{4N+1}}~ & C^TX \\
\text{s.t.}~ & AX  \leq B\in\mathbb{R}^{4N} \\
&X\geq 0,
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
X = \begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\b\\d\end{pmatrix}, &\qquad
C = \begin{pmatrix}m-1\\-n\\-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \\
A = \begin{pmatrix}
I_N & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\ 
-I_N & -I_N & -\mathbf{1}_N & 0 & -I_N \\
0 &0 & 0& I_N& 0\\
0 &0 &0 &I_N & -I_N
\end{pmatrix}&\in\mathbb{R}^{4N\times4N+1}, \qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix}b\\d\\\mathbf{1}_N\\\mathbf{0}_N\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{4N}. 
\end{aligned}
$$
Here I have defined $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_N)^T$ and likewise for $y$, $b$, and $d$. The objective has been negated to turn it into a maximization problem, which is more typical in linear programming. The inequality constraints determined by $A$ and $B$ read, in order, $x\leq b$, $-x-y-z\mathbf{1}_N \leq -d$, $b\leq \mathbf{1}_N$, and $b-d \leq \mathbf{0}_N$. Notice that the zeros on $A$ are actually zero matrices, and zero vectors in the 3rd block column to make the matrix multiplication work out.

One can then proceed via the simplex method to obtain a solution, although I doubt it will be pretty or even have a nice closed form.